# pass python var to bash

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I'm making a script to take pictures and write them to a folder created/named with the "data&time"

I made this part to create the directory and take the pictures

```
pathtoscript = "/home/pi/python-scripts"
current_time = time.localtime()[0:6]
dirfmt = "%4d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d"
dirpath = os.path.join(pathtoscript , dirfmt)
dirname = dirpath % current_time[0:6] #dirname created with date and time
os.mkdir(dirname) #mkdir
pictureName = dirname + "/image%02d.jpg" #path+name of pictures

camera.capture_sequence([pictureName % i for i in range(9)])
```

Then I would like to pass the dirname to a bash script (picturesToServer) which uploads the pictures to a server.
How can I do it?

```
cmd = '/home/pi/python-scripts/picturesToServer  >/dev/null 2>&1 &'
call ([cmd], shell=True)
```

Maybe I could stay in the python script scp the pictures to the server? I have a ssh-agent with the paraphrase set (ssh-add mykey).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the variable in the environment (it'll be available as a regular bash variable in the bash script, e.g. as `VAR_NAME` in the example below) by replacing your `call` with:

```
import subprocess    
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, env={"VAR_NAME": dirname})
```

Or pass it as a positional argument (it'll be available in `$1` in the script) by replacing your `cmd` with:

```
cmd = '/home/pi/python-scripts/picturesToServer >/dev/null 2>&1 "{0}" &'.format(dirname)
```

As a side note, consider **not** using `shell = True` when you call a subprocess. Using `shell = True` is a bad idea for [a lot of reasons that are documented in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)